# Port Forwarding for Remote Desktop

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, port-forwarding

I have two Mac notebooks at home, I have assigned them static private IPs. I have also set my router to a DynDNS address, which updates everytime my router gets a new public IP. I have enabled Screen Sharing on both notebooks.

I can successfully goto my router webpage using the DynDNS address. I understand I need to port-forward to get Screen Sharing to work from outside.

[image]

Lets assume, notebooks have private IP `192.168.1.2` and `192.168.1.3`

I am kind of lost here, would appreciate some help (I need to be able remote desktop to both notebooks)

Comment: please don't use tags to prefix the title, use the tags field

Comment: Perhaps edit "Remote Desktop" in the title to "Screen Sharing"? ARD uses a slew of other ports that are not necessary for Screen Sharing alone.

Comment: Which router do you have?

Comment: I would *NEVER* open a VNC port thru the firewall as it's a huge security risk. It has unlimited login attempts and the actual data is not encrypted - A quick search on shodan for macs with the vnc port open would bring up your computer in a list.

Please use a VPN instead - There isn't any need to share ports either, and also upgrade your cheap d-link/linksys router. There are known vulnerabilities for much of their kit and there is no guarantee of updated firmware either

Answer (score 0):

Take this as a hint/rough guide as I don't know how your router works. And I don't know what port or ports screen-sharing uses so I'll just type Pstart Pstop.

This also requires you to be able to tell the screen-sharing program client to use different ports than it normally uses.

Here is my guess:

In `Server IP Adress` you put `192.168.1.2`

`External Port Start`: Here you pick a number not in use for example `60100`
`External Port Stop` : Her you put in the number `60102 + (Pstop-Pstart)` to give your application a port span size it needs. (Very often the start and stop port is the same)

`Internal Port Start` put `Pstart`
`Internal Port Stop` put `Pstop`

And save.

Then you repeat for `192.168.1.3` but start with `61100` instead.

Then on the computer you want to use to connect **to** `192.168.1.3` and `192.168.1.2` you tell it to use you.dyndns.org adress and the ports specified above.

PS.
The ports I chose are just examples, you can use something else (keep it above 60000 to be safe)

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X uses the VNC protocol for screen sharing.

VNC uses port 5900 by default.

So forward port 5900 external to 192.168.1.2 port 5900, and port 5901 external to 192.168.1.3 port 5900.

When connecting from outside, enter your DynDNS host name. Desktop 0 (written :0) will be your first notebook, desktop 1 (:1) will be your second notebook.

On your router it looks like you put the external port in the "Custom Server" field and the internal IP address in the server IP field.  See your router's manual for more details.

Comment: Or is the problem that your router requires internal port be the same as the external port?

Comment: The addresses you connect to from outside will be vnc://yourdomain:5900/ or vnc://yourdomain:5901/, not :0 or :1